# libtool adding extra 'U' to .so file names

Tags: linux, autotools, libtool

I have a project built with autotools, divided into two folders; the first one, *lib*, creates some libraries, and the second one, *tools*, links against them.
The build  fails because libtool renames the libraries as follows while relinking:

```
mylib.1.0.0 -> mylib.1.0.0U
```

After the renaming occurs, anyway, the previous name is not restored, nor is a new *mylib.1.0.0* created, so the symbolic links like *mylib* still point to the name without the extra *U* and the linking fails.
Is there any way to avoid this? or maybe even to avoid the relinking at all? I'm using libtool version 1.5.6.

Comment: You should probably revert the last edit and answer the question properly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I got it...
The problem is easily reproducible with the following structure:

- a *lib* folder, building:

  - *liba*
  - *libb*, depending on *liba*
- a *src* folder, building *prog*, which links libb

Then you must specify this in lib/Makefile.am:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = \
    libb.la \
    liba.la
```

At that point a liba.so.1.0.0U file will be produced. Specifying instead (note that the order of the libraries is changed)

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = \
    liba.la \
    libb.la
```

the build works fine.
I agree that specifying things in the correct order is in any case the best thing to do; what is still unclear to me is if this is a libtool bug or not...